# Problem carrying Session over to other pages

Tags: php, session

I am able to login a user, but while processing to the next page (memebers area) I can't display any user info let alone print the `$_SESSION[email]`.  I am not sure what's up.  Below is the login code and the testing members are page.

Login page:

```
session_start(); 

//also in a real app you would get the id dynamically
$sql = "select `email`, `password` from `accounts` where `email` = '$_POST[email]'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $email = $row['email'];
    $secret = $row['password'];

    //we will echo these into the proper fields

}
mysql_free_result($query);

// Process the POST variables
$email = $_POST["email"];

//Variables
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST["email"];

$secret = $info['password'];

//Checks if there is a login cookie

if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))

//if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

{ 
    $email = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT email, password FROM accounts WHERE email =   '$email'")or die(mysql_error());

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) 

    {

        if (@ $info['password'] != $pass) 
        {
        }

        else

        {

            header("Location: home.php");

        }
    }

}

//if the login form is submitted 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted

    // makes sure they filled it in

    if(!$_POST['email'] | !$_POST['password']) {

        die('You did not fill in a required field.');

    }

    // checks it against the database

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

        $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);

    }

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT email,password FROM accounts WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'")or die(mysql_error());

    //Gives error if user dosen't exist

    $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if ($check2 == 0) {

        die('That user does not exist in our database. <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');
    }

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

        //gives error if the password is wrong

        if (@ $_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {

            die('Incorrect password, please try again');
        }

        else 

        { 

            // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

            $_POST['email'] = stripslashes($_POST['email']); 

            $hour = time() + 3600; 

            setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['email'], $hour); 

            setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);   

            //then redirect them to the members area 

            header("Location: home.php"); 

        } 

    } 

} 

else 

{    

    // if they are not logged in 

?> 

<?php 

}  

?>
```

home.php

```
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header('Location: login_test3.php'); die('<a  href="login_test3.php">Login first!</a>');
}

//Variables
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;

print $_SESSION['name'];
```

UPDATE

```
      Just realized the existing code gets in to the home.php file but will not echo anything.  But as soon as you hit refresh the session is gone.
```

Comment: A suggestion, don't let the end user know if its his username or password that's incorrect.  This can help alleviate account break ins

Comment: Oh yeah, its just test code to get working on the members area.  Will be fixed later.  Thanks Gumbo.

Comment: How is the session ID transmitted? Please tell us your current [configuration concerning the session ID](http://php.net/session.configuration) (i.e. *session.use\_cookies*, *session.use\_only\_cookies*, *session.use\_trans\_sid*).

Comment: why did someone down vote this question?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please reformat that code? It's really hard to comprehend with the indents and whitespace. Once it's back up, I'll do my best to help you.

One tip: input cleaning!

These functions have saved me a lot of trouble:

```
function forceInteger($variable) {
    return preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $variable);
}
function forceAlpha($variable) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", "", $variable);
}
function forceAlphaNum($variable) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-\.]/", "", $variable);
}
function forceAlphaNumNoSpace($variable) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]/", "", $variable);
}
```

I've found that dashes and periods are sufficient for most short strings. If taking in a textarea, run it through this:

```
function forceNaturalLanguage($variable) {
    return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-\.\?\!]/", "", $variable);
}
```

Here's my suggestion:
login.php (the script that handles authentication)

```
session_start();
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    // query database for email and password, where email is posted email
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `email` = '{$_POST[email]'}";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
        // there's one result - we got it!
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if ($_POST["password"] == $result["password"]) {
            // Successful auth.
            // Set session vars and redirect with header()
            $_SESSION["Authenticated"] = true;
            $_SESSION["FirstName"] = $result["FirstName"];
            $_SESSION["Email"] = $result["Email"];
            header("Location: /home.php?event=login");
            // Don't forget to exit(), otherwise some other code may run, causing unintended behaviours
        }
        else {
            // Password didn't match.
            exit("Incorrect password");
        }
    }
}
else {
    // No email match
    exit("Email not found.");
}
```

A couple points:
1. in double-quoted strings, to put an array value into the query, you must enclose it in {curly braces} like this: "Hi, {$_SESSION["FirstName"]}";

2. Don't *EVER* set session variables directly from user input. If you're grabbing it from the database, store it from there. That's the safest way.

3. Setting your own login cookie is pointless when you're using PHP sessions. If you want to change the name, try something like this:

```
ini_set("session.name","coolSession");
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're querying the database for the user's credentials twice? I'll edit my answer with some suggestions...

Comment: Thanks Alex.  But it still doesn't work.  Right now it just gives me a blank page.

Comment: Have you turned on errors?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",true);